# clang and/or LLVM-MingW creates only .dll file, no .a file

Tags: clang, mingw, llvm, llvm-mingw

My clang provided by [LLVM-MingW](https://github.com/mstorsjo/llvm-mingw) project creates only `.dll` file but not related `.a` file, what is the flag to build the `.a` file as well?

Chat-GPT suggests `--out-implib` option, if that's correct, I wonder what's the short-hand option for `--out-implib` option.

My makefile is auto-generated and huge, the important parts look like:

```
CC            = gcc
CXX           = g++
DEFINES       = -DUNICODE -D_WIN32 -DWIN32 -DQT_NO_USING_NAMESPACE -DPCRE_STATIC -DQT_NO_ICONV -DQT_BUILD_CORE_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x040800 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_OPENSSL -DQT_SQL
CFLAGS        = -pipe -Wno-deprecated-non-prototype -g -Wall -Wextra $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -std=c++1y -Wno-deprecated-register -Wno-ignored-attributes -fms-extensions -fpermissive -g -fexceptions -frtti -Wall -Wextra $(DEFINES)
INCPATH       = -ID:/projects/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib
QMAKE         = D:/projects/qt5/qtbase/bin/qmake.exe
DEL_FILE      = rm -f
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= test -d
MKDIR         = mkdir -p
COPY          = cp -f
COPY_FILE     = cp -f
COPY_DIR      = cp -f -R
INSTALL_FILE  = cp -f
INSTALL_PROGRAM = cp -f
INSTALL_DIR   = cp -f -R
DEL_FILE      = rm -f
SYMLINK       = $(QMAKE) -install ln -f -s
DEL_DIR       = rmdir
MOVE          = mv -f
TAR           = tar -cf
COMPRESS      = gzip -9f
DISTNAME      = Qt5Cored5.6.5
DISTDIR = D:/build/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/debug/Qt5Cored5.6.5
LINK          = g++
LFLAGS        = -shared -Wl,-subsystem,windows
LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS) -lole32 -luuid -lws2_32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -ldbghelp -lmpr -LD:/projects/qt5/qtbase/lib -lqtpcred
AR            = llvm-ar cqs
RANLIB        = 
SED           = sed
STRIP         = strip

QMAKE_TARGET  = Qt5Cored
DESTDIR       = D:/projects/qt5/qtbase/lib/
TARGET        = libQt5Cored.dll.5.6.5

####### Output directory

OBJECTS_DIR   = debug/

SOURCES       = D:/projects/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qstring_compat.cpp # ...

OBJECTS       = debug/qstring_compat.o # ...

# ...

####### Build rules

D:/projects/qt5/qtbase/lib/$(TARGET):  $(OBJECTS) $(SUBLIBS) $(OBJCOMP)  
    @test -d D:/projects/qt5/qtbase/lib/ || mkdir -p D:/projects/qt5/qtbase/lib/
    -$(DEL_FILE) $(TARGET)
    $(LINK) $(LFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS) $(OBJCOMP)
```